# layoutParams not changing

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I am trying to animate a horizontal list item dismiss
the alpha animation works and the layoutparam values also decrease over time
but for some reason that doesn't change the actual height of the list item.

```
@Override
protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
    final int initialHeight = view.getMeasuredHeight();


    if(interpolatedTime == 1){

        imageAdapter.remove(view, position);


    }else{

        view.getLayoutParams().height = initialHeight - (int)(initialHeight * interpolatedTime);
        view.setAlpha(1 - interpolatedTime);
        System.out.println("  v height = " + view.getHeight());
        System.out.println("  v layoutparams = " + view.getLayoutParams().height);
        view.forceLayout();
        view.invalidate();
        view.requestLayout();

    }
}
```

this is in the getView method of the imadeAdapter
and binBtn is the button which you touch to remove the listitem

```
      binBtn.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {


        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                  if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
                      {

                      View vp = (View) v.getParent();

                SqueezeAnimation ani = new SqueezeAnimation(this,vp,position);
                ani.setDuration(1000);
                v.startAnimation(ani);
```

change to this code after Tanis' answer but still same problem,
the getHeight() prints 674 and getLayoutParams().height prints 100

```
         else{
         RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lps = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100);

        view.setLayoutParams(lps);
        view.requestLayout();

        System.out.println("  v height = " + view.getHeight());
        System.out.println("  v layoutparams = " + view.getLayoutParams().height);
```

as a side note this is in the getView method of the imageadapter and that changes the height of that view, and ive tried passing in the backgroundfillIV to animate but still doesnt work

```
  View backgroundfillIV =  gridView.findViewById(R.id.backroundfillbar);
       double mult =  products.get(position).value/ products.get(0).value;
       backgroundfillIV.getLayoutParams().height = (int) ( (((bottleheight+20)*0.95)/mult));
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to call `setLayoutParams()` at some point to save your changes to the LayoutParams.

For example:

```
LayoutParams lps = view.getLayoutParams();
lps.height = initialHeight - (int)(initialHeight * interpolatedTime);
view.setAlpha(1 - interpolatedTime);
view.setLayoutParams(lps);
```

This is because the `getLayoutParams()` method is only returning a copy of the LayoutParams reference, not a reference to the LayoutParams themselves. There is a bit more in-depth discussion on this at [Does Java return by reference or value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7297944/1253844).

Comment: thanks for the answer, i really thought that this would solve it but it still doesn't change the height.

Comment: Instead of getting the existing LayoutParams, try creating an entirely new set of LayouParams.

Comment: i used `LayoutParams lps = new LayoutParams(100, 100);`  and that changes the layoutparams to 100 but still doesnt change the actual dimensions. I imported `import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;` is that the right one, there where a lot

Comment: You should use the LayoutParams from the View's parent. If this View is in a LinearLayout, use LinearLayout.LayoutParams; if the View is in a RelativeLayout, use RelativeLayout.LayoutParams; etc.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not sure what's wrong then. Make sure that you update your `backgroundfillIV` LayoutParam code similarly. Do some more debugging and experimenting (perhaps create a new app to play with) to figure out where it is going wrong.

Comment: view.requestLayout() may help, depending on the params changed may need to call requestLayout on parent view.

Comment: Perfect !! You save my day

Answer (score 0):

Not really a solution but the problem is with the HorizontalListView that I found because it works for a normal listview