# New Position of a image after Animation in android

Tags: android

Iam using a translate animation with bounce effect after animation finish i want the new top margin of a image but i still get a old top margin of a image that is a 0 my question is how i get a new margin

my main activity is.

```
    package iotechsolutions.location.ira;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.animation.Animation;
    import android.view.animation.Animation.AnimationListener;
    import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity 
    {
        Animation logoAnimation; // for moving logo
        Animation textAnimation; // for moving text
        ImageView mainLogo;
        TextView logoText;
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams param;
        View view;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            mainLogo=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.main_logo);
            logoText=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.logo_text);
            param=(LinearLayout.LayoutParams)mainLogo.getLayoutParams();
            logoAnimation=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.main_logo_translate);
            textAnimation=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.logo_text_translate);
            mainLogo.setAnimation(logoAnimation);
            logoAnimation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {


                    try
                    {

                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),Integer.toString( param.topMargin), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        Log.d("error",e.getMessage());
                    }


                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
                });
            logoAnimation.start();

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
        {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }

    }
```

but in toast i get the old margin position of a image how i get the new position of my image.

Comment: see this answer about `getLayoutParams()`

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17747123/layoutparams-not-changing

Comment: Actually, Animation in Android just Animating An Image from the View not the view itself, that's why you will got the original Margin.

Comment: try [this](http://nineoldandroids.com/). A good animation library for android.

Comment: but how i get a new margins

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing `param` just before using it:

```
try{
    param=(LinearLayout.LayoutParams)mainLogo.getLayoutParams();
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),Integer.toString( param.topMargin), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} catch{ ... }
```

Comment: i tried it but its not working i wana show text field just below logo that why ineed a location of it

Answer (score 0):

A [TranslateAnimation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html) ony affects a view's translation, not its actual [layout parameters](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html). So to answer your question, after the animation where you set `setFillAfter(true)`, you have to call [View.getTranslationX() / view.getTranslationY()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getTranslationX%28%29)

Again, note that TranslateAnimation will not change View's layout coordinates - they remain the same as before the animation. If you want to click the view, you have to click where the view would originally be placed, not where you see it on the screen.
If you want "true" moving, you need to adjust `LayoutParameters` of that view.