# What happen when a method returns a local variable in java? Does the local variable extends its life?

Tags: java, local-variables

I am reading Head First Java and learning the life and scope of local variables. The examples provided in the book did not include a method that returns its local variables.

```
public class GC {

    public static GC doStuff() { //I know the local variables die when the method completes
        GC newGC = new GC();     
        return newGC;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GC gc1; 

        gc1 = doStuff(); // The local variable gc1 gets the value of newGC. So 
    }
}
```

Comment: The value of the local variable is returned. The value of a local variable of a reference-type is the reference to a heap-object. The lifetime of heap-objects is controlled by the garbage collector.

Comment: It doesn't work that way. Learn about stack and heap and how they behave when calling methods.

Comment: Local variables' lifetime does NOT extend after the method has returned. Java methods are not _closures_. 
BUT: the objects created within a method have a completely different lifetime. The local variable only stores the _reference_ to the object. The local variable dies, but the object is still there, until garbage-collected.

Comment: @Goion no. The lifetime of a local variable ends when the surrounding block of code is exited, for primitives and non-primitives alike. But everything created through a `new` is created on the heap, and a variable to such an object is always a reference-variable. And again, the lifetime of heap-objects is controlled by the garbage collector.

Comment: Behind the question is, I think, a failure to appreciate the difference between objects and variables.  Variables never hold objects.  Variables hold references to objects.  (And I think the heap/stack distinction is not necessary to understand this).

Comment: @Turing85 sure, but the effective lifetime of an object ends when you have no more reference chains that can reach it, which I find more useful from the programming point of view.  The GC is merely an artifact that is needed because memory is finite.

Comment: @iggy that is not correct. The lifetime ends when the GC destroys the object. By overriding `finalize()`, we can "revive" otherwise unreachable objects.

Comment: That is being pedantic considering the question imo. @Turing85

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

When a method ends, the local variable is cleared.

Technically, all local items added (“pushed”) to the [stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)) during a method call are automatically cleared (“popped”) from the stack as the method ends/returns.

If a local variable is returned by a method, a **copy of the content of that variable** is what actually gets sent back to the calling method.

## Details

Here is a diagram of your example, with feline name changes to make matters more concrete (pun intended).

[image: diagram of the class Cat and its transitions during object creation]

First thing you do is establish a reference variable named `fluffy` that is intended to hold a reference to a `Cat` object. That variable by default holds no reference, holding nothing at all until later when a reference might eventually be assigned. We call that state `null`, pointing to no object at all.

Then you make a call to the `static` method `Cat.makeCat`. Upon executing the `makeCat()` part, flow-of-control jumps to the other method.

When executing `new Cat()`, you are doing *two* things:

- Instantiating an object, that is, grabbing a piece of memory (in the heap) that has bytes ready to hold the various fields defined by the class. The class is like a cookie-cutter, and each instance (each object) is like a cookie cut from memory in place of dough.
- Capturing a reference to that object, that is, remembering the location in memory where that object lives.

The reference (pointer) is the return value from your call to `new Cat()`. That reference is stored in your local variable `c` (on the stack).

Then you call `return c`. That sends a xerox copy of the reference (the address in memory) back to the calling method. The stack pops the items held for that method call, so the reference held in variable named `c` is cleared, poof!, gone.

The flow-of-control, along with that copy of the reference, returns back to the calling method named `main`. The copy of the reference is placed in a local variable named `fluffy` (on the stack).

➥ Regarding the main point of your Question: The local variable `c` lived and died, while its *contents* were copied by the `returns` statement to the calling method.

Your app then ends, exiting at the end of the `main` method. Again the stack pops the items for that method call, and the `fluffy` variable and its contents are cleared, poof!, gone. The `Cat` object we instantiated is still floating around in memory. That `Cat` object is now a candidate for garbage collection, eventually to be cleared from memory, and that memory free to be reassigned to some other use such as holding a new object. Of course, all of this paragraph is moot, as app is exiting and the [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) shutting down, and all related memory is cleared.

The local variables `fluffy` and `c` eventually end up both pointing to the same object in memory, each variable technically holding the equivalent of the memory address of that single `Cat` object.

These concepts of pointers/references with a memory address, stack and heap, and [returning by reference versus returning by value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7297937/642706), are tricky to get at first, quite abstract and fuzzy. Eventually, if you keep at it, the concepts pop into place, becoming amazingly clear and simple. Until then, keep on coding. In day-to-day work, Java programmers do not consciously reflect on these concepts. We just think of `fluffy` and `c` as holding a cat, with the cat being passed around from method to method, though that is not technically accurate.

Comment: AMAZING! Thank you so much for the explanation. I understand it now.